# RSpec mock service and corresponding method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to mock a service that returns the integer `0` when called with `get_auth_key.api_response_code`.

This is what I have so far:

```
  before(:each) do
    PolicyObjects::BpointRequestPolicy.any_instance.stub(:get_auth_key).and_return(OpenStruct.new(api_response_code: 0))
  end
```

I would like to avoid creating a class for this in the test as I believe it's overkill. Somewhere in the codebase, `response = PolicyObjects::BpointRequestPolicy.new(...)` gets called and then compared: `if response.api_response_code == 0`. I would like it to return `0` to hit conditionals in my test.

What is the best practice or easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use case for a double or better an `instance_double` if you know the class you're mocking out:

```
let(:api_resonse) { instance_double("SomeResponseClass", api_response_code: 0) }  

before(:each) do 
  PolicyObjects::BpointRequestPolicy.any_instance.stub(:get_auth_key).and_return(api_response)
end
```